Is $1 + o(1)$ the same as $\Theta(1)$?
Many theoretical papers used something like $N(1+o(1))$ complexity, but is it the same as saying $\Theta(N)$?

No, it's a more precise bound than $\Theta(N)$. Consider $2N$. It fits the $\Theta(N)$ bound, but does not fit $N(1+o(1))$ bound, because $2>1+o(1)$.
On the other hand, a function like $N\left(1+\frac 1{\log n}\right)$ fits this bound.
